# Magento2: how to get product video by product id or sku?

Tags: magento2, product-page, product-video

I've tried to get video on product page on other place not on gallery. But i can't retrieve it. I've seen it stored on `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`

I want to get it proper not direct query. anybody knows proper way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to use **$product->getMediaGalleryImages()**

```
$galleryImages = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
if ($galleryImages) {
    foreach ($galleryImages as $image) {
        $imageData = $image->getData();

        // Check media type
        if (isset($imageData['media_type']) && $imageData['media_type'] == 'external-video') {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Only 1 changes condition should be `$imageData['media_type'] == 'external-video'` instead of `$imageData['media_type'] == 'external_video'`