# Magento 2: How to check product has video or not

Tags: magento2, product, product-list, product-video

In the product `list.phtml` I want to check

```
if(product has video)
{
    show button video
}else
{
    not show button video
}
```

[image]

Any way to solve it? Thank in advance.

Comment: this might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176631/magento2-how-to-get-product-video-by-product-id-or-sku?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I tried, but it does not work for me

Comment: You followed magento standard for add video or any third party video you added?

Comment: I followed the Magento standard. Do you have any idea?